# Unable to find correct selector for vault on Kubernetes with MicroK8s

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, microk8s

I am currently working for the first time with a vault and I am encountering an issue. I am following the official guide from hashicorp to install the vault on a Kubernetes cluster and I am running it with MicroK8s.

However, I am not able to unseal my vault. As you can see it is running but when I try to use the selector to be able to unseal afterwards, it doesn't find the namespace.

I am fairly new to this but I wasn't able to find the solution online.

Any help would be appreciated.

Please find below the console output.

Thank you !

```
root@vault-dev:/home/dev# kubectl --namespace="vault" get pods
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
vault-0                                0/1     Pending   0          12m
vault-1                                0/1     Pending   0          12m
vault-2                                0/1     Pending   0          12m
vault-3                                0/1     Pending   0          12m
vault-4                                0/1     Pending   0          12m
vault-agent-injector-7969bb745-nmswj   1/1     Running   0          12m
root@vault-dev:/home/dev# kubectl exec --stdin=true --tty=true vault-0 -- vault operator init
Error from server (NotFound): pods "vault-0" not found
root@vault-dev:/home/dev# kubectl --namespace="vault" get pods
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
vault-0                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
vault-1                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
vault-2                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
vault-3                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
vault-4                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
vault-agent-injector-7969bb745-nmswj   1/1     Running   0          15m
root@vault-dev:/home/dev# kubectl --namespace="vault" get all
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/vault-0                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
pod/vault-1                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
pod/vault-2                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
pod/vault-3                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
pod/vault-4                                0/1     Pending   0          15m
pod/vault-agent-injector-7969bb745-nmswj   1/1     Running   0          15m

NAME                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
service/vault-internal             ClusterIP      None             <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP   15m
service/vault-ui                   LoadBalancer   REDACTED    <pending>     8200:32269/TCP      15m
service/vault-standby              ClusterIP      REDACTED    <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP   15m
service/vault-agent-injector-svc   ClusterIP      REDACTED        <none>        443/TCP             15m
service/vault                      ClusterIP      REDACTED       <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP   15m
service/vault-active               ClusterIP      REDACTED       <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP   15m

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/vault-agent-injector   1/1     1            1           15m

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/vault-agent-injector-7969bb745   1         1         1       15m

NAME                     READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/vault   0/5     15m
root@vault-dev:/home/dev# kubectl get pods --selector='statefulset.apps/name=vault' --namespace=' vault'
No resources found in  vault namespace.
```

Comment: Vault pods are Pending, you need to do a kubectl describe pod vault-0 to check why, maybe wrong NodeSelectors?

Comment: Hi Paltaa! Thank you for your answer. There were/are two mistakes in my previous configuration. First of all, the simplest, I simply didn't change the namespace I was working with. Which made it very complicated to execute any type of command. The second mistake is that my pods are not assigned to any node. This is my time now to try to figure this one out. Thanks for your answer!